# Trying to install kubuntu from disc but can't do it

Tags: software-installation

So I have Windows 10 on my laptop, and it dual boots with Ubuntu. I wanted to take Ubuntu off and use kubuntu 17.04. so I downloaded the iso, burned it on to a disk. Rebooted. But it only keeps booting to the screen where I choose windows or Ubuntu to boot into. Will not show the disk or pull it up at all. Tried several times. So I redownloaded the file again. Burned it to a new disk again. And same thing. Anyone know how I can boot from the disk so I can just erase Ubuntu and install kubuntu alongside windows as well? Thanks in advance. Spent 3 hours last night trying to figure it out with no luck.

Comment: Did you try check the BIOS to enable and reconfigure the boot order?

Comment: F-2 Key on "most" laptops will bring up the Bios during Pre-boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not have any technical problems with your Ubuntu but want to switch for other reasons, maybe its an option to not un-install it at all. You can just install Kubuntu 'on top'.
That works nicely, because in all variants the underlying Linux is actually the same. The differenc is only in the desktop and some software choices.

I do not know Kubuntu actually, but I did the same thing to get from Ubuntu to Xubuntu. Here is what I did:

1. Just start Ubuntu as usual and open a Terminal
2. Install the small program "tasksel", which is not installed by default. If you are not sure, just enter the command, it will do nothing if it is installed already

   sudo apt install tasksel

It will ask your password.

3. Run tasksel. Its will give you a small list of packages to install. The nice thing is that it can install a full desktop flavour with one click.

   sudo tasksel

use the cursor keys up and down and SPACE bar to select a package to install. I went to "Xubuntu-desktop", pressed space, then TAB to get to the OK button and ENTER. Then it started the installation. Have a coffee.

4. When done your are either logged off, or just manually log off.
5. In the login window, you see a little button which pops out a list. For me it gave Ubuntu, Xubuntu and xfce. These are the different desktop themes. I did chose Xununtu and it got me to the Xubuntu desktop.

The nice thing is that you can keep multiple desktops in parallel. They do not take too much space. If you want you just uninstall the old one.

Hope it helps